# Make a list of all sites in a site collection

Tags: list, site-collection

Is it possible to obtain a list of all sites in the site collection, such that it can be used e.g. in a lookup column?

So far I have found two ways of getting a display of my sites:

1. Opening *Site settings* and then *Site hierarchy* on the top level site.
2. Adding a *content search* webpart with a custom query (as described [here](https://sharegate.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-content-search-site-portal)).

While these methods are good ways to have a look at your site collection, I need a way to put together a sharepoint list for further use in workflows etc. How can that be archieved?
I am a site collection administrator and my company is running SP 2013 on premise.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following [REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom) call to get a "list of lists" on your site.

`https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists`

To get a list of subsites within the current Site Collection, do:

`https://{site_url}/_api/web/webs`

To get a list of all sites in the environment, use the Search functions of the API, the following query gets all site collections and all subsites:

`https://{site_url}/_api/search/query?
querytext='contentclass:STS_Site contentclass:STS_Web'
&selectproperties='Title,Path'`

If you just want to get top-level site collections without the subsites, just omit the `contentclass:STS_Web`.

If you have Workflow Services installed in order to create a workflow that uses the 2013 Workflow engine (as opposed the 2010 engine that is still the default in SP2013), then you can call this service directly from your workflow.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not need a "list of lists", but a "list of sites". Do you know how that can be archieved via REST? I have already looked into the documentation for a few hours yesterday, but so far without luck.

Comment: I edited the answer to also include getting sites from REST API query.

Comment: Also added another option to just get subsites of the current site collection.

Comment: Thank you @willman, that looks very promising!